# Win32 and Acrobat

Tags: pdf, winapi, plugins

I have a simple Win32 app writen in C, in which I would like to open PDFs. I know I can compile and link to Poppler library, but is there a way to use Acrobat Reader? Kind of like what browsers do, if you have Reader installed, they are automatically able to display PDF in a window though some plugin interface. The problem is, I never used a plugin, not wrote such an interface. How to? Is it also possible to install Reader afterward and somehow make the app aware of its presence?

I would also like to control, say, the zoom. And what the PDF could be in memory, as well.

Edit:

I just found this [1]:
"If you have installed Adobe Reader, you can add a COM reference to the PDf viewer ActiveX control in VisualStudio and use it inside a WindowsFormsHost control."
but I don't understand what does it says: how do I create "COM reference" and use "WindowsFormsHost" in plain Win32 C?

[1] [PDF Libraries to Display a PDF document in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014658/pdf-libraries-to-display-a-pdf-document-in-wpf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win32: displaying PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330336/win32-displaying-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

On windows if you type `mypdf.pdf` and hit return in a Command Prompt it opens the pdf in the associated application <sup><sub>(in most cases Adobe Reader)</sub></sup>. So in c# I start a new process with the pdf as the *file to run*.

You should be able to do something similar in c without bothering with plugins.

Comment: Yes, but I also would like to control, say, the zoom. And what the PDF could be in memory, as well..

Comment: @Lars - I'm pretty sure you can't automate Adobe Reader at all. You'll need a third party plug-in to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "3rd party"? A plugin for Acrobat? Which in turn is controlled by my app?

Comment: @Lars - I may have been unclear I did not mean that `you'll need a plug-in to control Adobe Reader` (I don't think there is one). I meant some code, a library or a dll (that can render the pdf) provided by someone else that you can control from your application (like poppler that you mentioned).

Comment: That's so unfortunate... Cocoa has PDFKit, Poppler is extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Nifle said, if instead of running it as a separate application you want to run Acrobat Reader as a plugin within your application's window (as for example IE runs it within IE's window), [Adobe Acrobat Reader download page](http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-Acrobat-Reader-32-bit/3000-2378_4-8338119.html) says,

> An ActiveX control for Internet Explorer and a plug-in for Netscape Navigator are included and automatically installed in the browser of your choice.

The plug-in technology is probably the technology called [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX).