# Win32: displaying PDF

Tags: pdf, winapi

I have a simple Win32 C app, which I would like to enable to display PDFs (they do not have to be files - they could be in-memory as well). I would like to control at least the zoom level and whether is should be shown as single, standalone pages or continuous "flow" of pages. I'm asking for anything else than Acrobat Reader, Poppler and Sumatra, preferably something which integrates with a dialog-based app nicely.

Answer (score 2):

What about not using Sumatra itself, but [mupdf](http://mupdf.com/), which Sumatra is built atop?

Comment: Only 56 of those are MuPDF itself.

Comment: @Lars Kanto: so what? Not all of these bugs are even confirmed (anybody can submit a bug report, even if he didn't know how to correctly operate the program), and many of these bugs are not *blockers*. Thanks open source, you even get to know publicly which problems have been reported in a bug database at all. Can you say this about all closed-source/commercial applications?!?