# Ax2012:How can I upload and print an external PDF file

Tags: printing, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm a beginner student working on a project for `AX2012`. I have an external PDF file to print . For this,I am looking for a solution to upload, display and then print the PDF from an external file when I click a button.

I have test this job

```
static void AALpdfprint(Args _args)
{
    PrintJobSettings    printJobSettings = new PrintJobSettings();
    Dialog              dialog = new Dialog();
    DialogField         dialogFileName;
    str                 adobeExe;
    str                 adobeParm;
;

    dialogFileName = dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(Filenameopen), "immatriculation");

    if (dialog.run())
    {
        printJobSettings.printerSettings('SysPrintForm');
        adobeExe = WinAPI::findExecutable(dialogFileName.value());

        adobeParm = strFmt(' /t "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"',
                           dialogFileName.value(),
                           printJobSettings.printerPrinterName(),
                           printJobSettings.printerDriverName(),
                           printJobSettings.printerPortName());

        winAPI::shellExecute(adobeExe,  adobeParm);
    }
}
```

Here i can upload the file correctly, but i want display it before printing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other [command line options](http://htipe.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/adobe-acrobat-command-line-options/) to Acrobat reader?

What [applies to other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329653/win32-and-acrobat) applies to X++ as well.